# How to define the Hamiltonian properly in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hamiltonian

In a rigorous fashion, how does one define the Hamiltonian of QFT as

$$\hat{H}(t) = \int d^3x \hat{\mathcal{H}}(x, t)$$

For now I'm ignoring the fact that $\hat{\mathcal{H}}$ itself may be ill-defined since it involves product of distributions. Let's assume that $\hat{\mathcal{H}}$ is a properly defined operator-valued distribution.

First how does one take the integral of a distribution like this? While one could take something resembling an integral as $\hat{\mathcal{H}}[\phi]$ if $\mathcal{H}$ had compact support and $\phi = 1$ on that support, there's no guarantee that this is possible in general. Is it possible for instance to define the operator-valued distribution as the limit of a sequence of operator-valued functions and take something akin to

$$\hat{H}(t) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int d^3x \hat{\mathcal{H}}_n(x,t)$$

assuming that the limit can commute with the integral. Also, what would be the integral used here, is it one of those projection-valued measure?

Alternatively, can I define it as

$$\hat{H}(t) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \hat{\mathcal{H}}[\phi_n]$$

for $\phi_n$ a test function equal to $1$ on a compact support of ever increasing size?