# Distributions in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator, dirac-delta-distributions

If field operators are really distributions then surely objects like the commutator, any correlation functions or even the free theory lagrangians are all ill-defined since products of distributions are not well defined?

Comment: Sure, quantum field theory as practiced by many physicists is mathematically ill-defined. Do you have a more specific question about that? As it stands, it is hard to tell what exactly you expect as an answer here.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/337423/50583 (on the general nature of quantum fields mathematically), https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449676/50583 (on a specific issue with operator-valued distributions vs. the usual approach)

Comment: Apart from the links suggested by @ACuriousMind I also suggest you see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/684960/  and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/330536/